# Injecting angular 4 header component to a component main component with pug

Tags: angular, angular-components

I tried to include the header in the main component but in doesn't show. When i check the inspect element. It looks like this

[inspect elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWJN.png)

It looks like an iframe.
This is my main.component.ts:

```js
import { HeaderComponent } from "../../components";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: '<app-header></app-header>',
  styles: [require('./main.component.scss')]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Here is my header.component.ts file:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: require('./header.component.pug'),
  styles: [require('./header.component.scss')]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

How can I change this to include my component correctly?

Comment: You should use styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'] instead of that require, also you don't need to import your header component into the main with the import statement. Won't solve your issue though. Could you post your HeaderComponent?

Comment: Did you add your HeaderComponent to the app module? Is the selector in your header component `app-header`?

Comment: I've added my header component in the app.modules.ts already. Here's my code
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: require('./header.component.pug'),
      styles: [require('./header.component.scss')]
    })
    export class HeaderComponent {
      constructor() { }
    }`

Comment: the template URL is wrong. it should be a String to a .html file.

Comment: Thank you!!! My scss file is not detectable when i've used this instead styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']

Comment: Check for your configuration then, maybe it's not including .scss files properly. Does it work with `styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']` (css files)? I **strongly** recommend you to look into fixing this in order to use the property correctly.

Comment: I'm using this with webpack. so it's working. Thank you anyway

Comment: Ok, please accept my answer below solving your header issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templateUrl for an Angular component should be a String pointing to a .html file.

header.component.html

```
<div>{{title}}</div>
```

header.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'  // <-- Like this
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  title = "Header works!";
}
```

Comment: this is angular with pug and scss not angular with html and css only

Comment: pug generates html? then use that file! see here https://hackernoon.com/using-pug-jade-with-angular-with-cli-5592b7ee24e6